# Element.Disabled throws error as element not found

Tags: c#, selenium-webdriver

for my test I need this element.Disabled  to return false.

When test reaches to a page where that element is not displayed , test gets failed with element not found.

below  code  fails as username textbox doesnot display on the page

```
if (VerifyUsernameTextBox())
{
do something
}

public bool VerifyUsernameTextBox()
        {
            return username.Displayed;  // code fails with no element found while return false is expected .

}
```

What to do so I get element.Displayed as false .

Comment: Please, provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Examples](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You find the element by `driver.findElement()`, right?
Remember, `findElement` throws an exception if it doesn't find an element, so you need to properly handle it.

You can do like this:

```
    private bool IsUsernamePresent(By by)
    {
        try
        {
            driver.findElement(by);
            return true;
        }
        catch (NoSuchElementException)
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
```

then

```
public bool VerifyUsernameTextBox()
{
    return IsUsernamePresent(By.Id("element_username_id"));
}
```

Comment: @Vidushi: You are welcome. Pls click on the tick symbol if it resolved your issue. Thanks.